# better way to find files on linux that are mounted on a block device?

Tags: linux, find

I'm trying to find all the files that are on a given host using "find" and I want to ignore paths like /dev, /proc, etc.

I will also ignore nfs mount points for this exercise.

I am looking to get more data than mlocate provides natively like ctime, uid, gid, etc.

My idea was to look into /proc/filesystems and get the list of filesystems that would be mounted on block devices (i.e. ignore ^nodev lines) and then pass those to "find" like so

```
fslist=$(grep -v "^nodev" /proc/filesystems)
```

and then send that to find with

```
for fs in $(echo $fslist)
do
find / -fstype $fs >> output
done
```

Is there perhaps a better way to do this?

I'm trying to avoid those files that are almost pointless to record anyway

Thank you.

Comment: something like this? `find -not -path '/dev*' -not -path '/proc*'` ?

Comment: @Sundeep unfortunately, that doesn't really cover everything. In fact, in RHEL 7, you see things like /sys, /run and with in /sys/cgroup etc.

Comment: either construct all paths you need or exclude those you don't need...